# get bigdata from mysql for android table

Tags: android, mysql

on which way I could load this data in my androidapp.
whats your expression, what do you think is the best way.
maybe I could do something like, loading 100 entries and wait until the user has seen the last one and then load again the other one. but how could I do this.
is it the best way to get data from sql with a php script or is there a better way?

Comment: this is a poor question

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

**There have 2 ways**:

1. **load all data into cursor**

   because the cursor most hold 2M data in memory,

   when you scroll listview down/up,it will auto requery().

   And there is no performance/memory issue by this way.
2. **load data into cursor by page**

   by this method,need youself requery()

**when use the first way or second way?**

if you don't delete/update data when scroll listview,

i sugeest you use the first way.

else use the second way.